# Aptana 3 Changes Show in Other Branches

Tags: git, aptana, aptana3

I'm a newbie to development, and for the first time, I'm trying to manage multiple branches for a project - development and production.  I'm using Aptana Studio 3 for my Rails 3 project and I'm getting confused because when I switch between branches in Aptana, I can see the changes made in the other branch.

For example, if I change File a.doc in my dev branch, when I switch to my production branch, I also see the changes in the file.  Shouldn't master maintain the previous version (ie not show the changes made in dev) until I merge dev into production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is by design, if the file you are editing looks the same at the tips of the 2 branches that you are switching between, you can switch branches. The key to this is that you have not committed your change yet so it is not part of any branch yet. If you commit that change and checkout the other branch, you will see that the file goes back to what it was on the other branch.